# How to anchor color scale to the min / max for each row using pheatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I'm currently using pheatmap in R to create a heatmap of gene expressions from single cell data.

The problem I am currently having is that I can't seem to replicate the relative color scale used in other heatmap generators, such as Morpheus: https://software.broadinstitute.org/morpheus/

To elaborate, in Morpheus the color scale can be anchored to the minimum and maximum expression values for each row. For example, assuming the color scale is something simple like `c('dark_blue', 'blue', 'bright_blue', 'white', 'bright_red', 'red', 'dark_red')` and I provide a matrix that looks like `t(data.frame(row1=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), row2=c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))),` Morpheus will color 0 dark blue and 6 dark red in the first row, while 10 will be dark blue and 16 will be dark red in the second row. The color bar then represents the relative min and max for each row.

Note that this is not the same thing as simply scaling the data, which is what I have been doing in pheatmap. The problem is that if I have something like `t(data.frame(row1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), row2=c(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))`, then even scaling the data will not allow 6 (~1.34 after scaling) to be colored dark red, since the color scale is anchored to the min (~-0.41 after scaling) and max (~2.04 after scaling) for the whole heatmap.

I don't doubt that there is a simple way to achieve this, but I wasn't able to figure it out by looking through the basic documentation. I also understand that displaying the heatmap in this manner won't allow any comparison between genes, but that is not particularly important for my uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your data by row like this:

```
mat <- t(data.frame(row1=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), row2=c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)))
mat2 <- t(apply(mat, 1, scale))
```

Then `pheatmap` has the argument `cluster_cols` which you can set to `FALSE`. Putting it all together this will make both 0 and 10 dark blue in the final heatmap

```
pheatmap(mat2, cluster_cols = F)
```

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified a bit more. I have already been scaling the data when creating the heatmap with pheatmap. For the first example set I gave, the results between Morpheus and pheatmap will be the same despite the methodology being different. For the second example, pheatmap will produce a heat map where 10 (~2.04 after scaling) will be dark red, whereas 6 (~1.34 after scaling) will not be despite being the highest value in its row. Morpheus would produce a heat map where both 1 and 0 are dark blue, and 6 and 10 are dark red, because they are the respective min and max for their rows.

Comment: run the same code w this data `mat <- t(data.frame(row1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), row2=c(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))`. 6 and 10 are red, 10 darker bc its more of an outlier.